# Open a file embedded in a VSTO Addin?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, embed

I'd like to include a "help" file in my Outlook VSTO addin. I'd like it to just be a word doc which is somehow embedded in the addin in such a way that it doesn't just open the file from a network drive, but rather the word doc itself is part of the installed VSTO and the user can just open it from the addin. I am working in VB.NET. Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the file as resource. Using visual studio it's as easy as peeling a banana. I use it to store my manual (A Word file).